# What does "this" do in the following code

Tags: java, this

I am trying to make a tic tac toe board using the following code. I do not understand what

button.addActionListener(this);

is doing and why `this` is being used there.

```
package guicollection;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTicTacToe extends GUIcollection
        implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel pane1;

    void drawTicTacToe() {

        DrawTicTacToe frame = new DrawTicTacToe();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        pane1 = new JPanel();

        pane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        pane1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        window.add(pane1);

        button = new JButton("Prss me");
        window.add(button);
        **button.addActionListener(this);**

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Graphics paper = pane1.getGraphics();
        paper.drawLine(90, 30, 90, 120);
        paper.drawLine(135, 30, 135, 120);
        paper.drawLine(60, 60, 165, 60);
        paper.drawLine(60, 90, 165, 90);


    }

}
```

Why can't I replace `this` with actionPerformed ?

Comment: Your question "Why can't I replace this with actionPerformed?" makes no sense.  The "this" is refering to a DrawTicTacToe object which implements the interface ActionListener while "actionPerformed" is method.  addActionListener takes an instance of ActionListener as an argument.

Comment: When its already commented that it is an exact duplicate then why do people give answers to the question. We should use the existing resources.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar There's a name for those people: *karma vultures*.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonaddActionListenerActionListeneract.htm

always read the documentation before asking a question.

`JButton.addActionListener(ActionListener act)` needs a parameter of the type ActionListener, `actionPerformed` is a method collection, which is not the right type. `this` is the current object, which is of the types  DrawTicTacToe, GUIcolletion and ActionListener (and probably some more, depending on what the superclasses of these are).

Answer (score 0):

It is registering the current instance of your DrawTicTacToe class as a Listener of that button.  When the button is clicked, your actionPerformed method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

"this" here refers to ActionListener interface which is implemented by the current instance of DrawTicTacToe class.It implies that with this line of code we have bound our ActionListener with the button so that whenever the particular event occurs for the button its actionPerformed method will be called

Comment: That I understood but where the actionPerformed method is invoked so that it would draw the tic tac toe board ?  Does it have to be named exactly actionPerformed ? I changed its name and I got error. I am a new bie ...

Comment: actionPerformed method is provided by ActionListener interface which your DrawTicTacToe class has implemented.We are overriding this method from that interface and giving it our own implementation.Hence you cannot use any other name for it because the ActionListener API has given you this callback which is called every time the button is clicked and it has given you the freedom of implementing whatever you want on the click of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a method will need to refer to the object that invoked it. To allow this, Java defines the
     ***this*** keyword. ***this*** can be used inside any method to refer to the current object. That is, ***this*** is always a reference to the object on which the method was invoked. You can use ***this*** anywhere a reference to an object of the current class' type is permitted.

In your case **this** refers to DrawTicTacToe class object.
so

```
 button.addActionListener(this);
```

means that the actions for this ActionListener can be found in **this** class
that is in DrawTicTacToe